# Combine 4 balls out of G Glasses. How many combination can be found before no balls are left?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Problem:**
There are G glasses. In each of the glasses there is a number of balls. The number of balls can differ between the glasses. 4 balls form a tuple. You can only pick at most one ball from each glass when creating a tuple.

**Question:**
What is the maximum number T of tuples that can be created until less than 4 balls are left?

---

**Example:**
with G=5 glasses containing balls (Glass A contains balls a1,a2...) :

- Glass A: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5
- Glass B: b1, b2, b3, b4
- Glass C: c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
- Glass D: d1, d2, d3, d4, d5
- Glass E: e1, e2, e3, e4, e5

Here the solution would be T=6 (no balls left at the end) with for example:

1. (a1,b1,c1,d1)
2. (a2,b2,c2,e1)
3. (a3,c3,d2,e2)
4. (a4,b3,d3,e3)
5. (b4,c4,d4,e4)
6. (a5,c5,d5,e5)

Comment: If you form each tuple from the four glasses with the most balls remaining, you will form the maximum number of tuples.

Comment: Thank you for this hint - I understand that but I do not see the connection to the formula which tells me what T is.

Comment: Not sure... that hint leaves some work to do!  Call the contents of the glasses, in decreasing order, $n_1 \ge n_2 \ge n_3 \ge \ldots \ge n_G$.  Then if $n_3 \ge \sum_{i=4} n_i$, then $T=\sum_{i=4} n_i$.  What happens in the other case, where $n_3 < \sum_{i=4} n_i$?

Comment: Let $S_k = \sum_{i=k}^G n_i$ and consider the cases $(n_3 \ge S_4), (n_2 \ge S_4 > n_3), (n_1 \ge S_4 > n_2),$ and $n_1 < S_4$ separately.